# Terraform string manipulation to remove X elements

Tags: terraform

I have several strings that I just want to get a subset of like so:

`my-bucket-customer-staging-ie-app-data`

`my-bucket-customer2-longname-prod-uk-app-data`

and I just need to get the customers name from the string, so with the above examples I'd be left with

`customer`

`customer2-longname`

There's probably a simple way of doing this with regex although I've failed miserably in my attempts.

I'm able to strip the first part of the string using

`trimprefix("my-bucket-customer-staging-ie-app-data", "my-bucket-")`

`trimprefix("my-bucket-customer-longname-prod-uk-app-data", "my-bucket-")`

resulting in

`customer-staging-ie-app-data`

`customer-longname-prod-uk-app-data`

However Terraform's trimsuffix won't work as there can be several different regions/environments used.

What I'd like to do is slice the string and ignore the last 4 elements, which should then return the customer name regardless of whether it contains an additional delimiter in it.

Something like this captures the customer, however fails for long customer names:

`element(split("-",trimprefix("my-bucket-customer-staging-uk-app-data", "my-bucket-")), length(split("-",trimprefix("my-bucket-customer-staging-uk-app-data", "my-bucket-")))-5)`

`customer`

and is also quite messy.

Is there a more obvious solution I'm missing

Comment: You could use the `prefix` argument and control what the prefix of the bucket name should be, if that helps in any way. The rest of the bucket name would be random in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's what regex is for.

```
> try(one(regex("\\w*-\\w*-(\\w*(?:-\\w*)*)-\\w*-\\w*-\\w*-\\w*","my-bucket-customer-staging-ie-app-data")),"")
"customer"
> try(one(regex("\\w*-\\w*-(\\w*(?:-\\w*)*)-\\w*-\\w*-\\w*-\\w*","my-bucket-customer2-longname-prod-uk-app-data")),"")
"customer2-longname"
> try(one(regex("\\w*-\\w*-(\\w*(?:-\\w*)*)-\\w*-\\w*-\\w*-\\w*","my-bucket-customer2-longname-even-longer-prod-uk-app-data")),"")
"customer2-longname-even-longer"
```

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex